# Join the data of different Lists present in different classes

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
public class EmpManagement
{
    public List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

    //Method for adding new employee
    public void AddEmp(Employee emp)
    {
        empList.Add(emp);
    }

    public void displayEmp(Employee emp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + emp.Empname + "]");
    }

    //Method for viewing all employees
    public void ShowEmp()
    {
        foreach (var e in empList)
        {
            displayEmp(e);
        }
    }
}


public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public Role(string roleName)
    {
        RoleName = roleName;
    }
}


public class RoleManagement
{
    public List<Role> RoleList = new List<Role>();

    //Method for adding roles
    public void RoleAdd(Role role)
    {
        RoleList.Add(role);
    }

    //Method for viewing all roles
    public void displayRole()
    {
        foreach (var e in RoleList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.RoleName);
        }
    }
}
```

Join the above two lists in a different class

How can i add below two Lists into another list of different class

I am facing a problem while using a interface in one class and extending into the new class

I am also unable to use contains keyword, the compiler says that the name does not exist in current context

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you want to do? "_Join the above two lists in a different class_" is a bit vague. The two classes you've shown are of different types, so you can't "join" them (whatever that means) directly. I guess you want to use this "different class" you mentioned, but since you didn't include that, we don't know what you want to do. Also, what does the interface have to do with it, and how are you trying to use `Contains`? You haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Things like `Union`, `Intersect`, and `Except` are what you're looking for I think. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-7.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot join two lists of different types into a single list. But you could still take casting into consideration, and cast the two data types into a single data type and then join the two lists into a single list.
for more information, you could refer to the following :

[https://linuxhint.com/csharp-combine-two-lists/#:~:text=We%20will%20demonstrate%20an%20example,cs%E2%80%9D%20extension](https://linuxhint.com/csharp-combine-two-lists/#:%7E:text=We%20will%20demonstrate%20an%20example,cs%E2%80%9D%20extension).

Answer (score 1):

First, declare two lists and join these two in another list.
Please check the example below

```
List <string> list1 = new List <string>(){"L1L1","L1L2","L1L3"};
List <string> list2 = new List <string>(){"L2L1","L2L2","L2L3"};
List<string> joinList = list1.Join(list2);
```

Please see another example which is given below.

```
public class Role
{
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Role2
{
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RoleManagement
{
   public List<Role> r1 = new List<Role>();
   public List<Role> r2 = new List<Role>();

   List<string> joinList2 = r1.Join(r2);
}
```